# Slow Insert speed on Servers but fast on Local Machines

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-performance

We have found that insertions on our servers are extremely slow (40+ seconds), but when we use the same DB with the same insert script on our local computers it is almost instant.

Our servers are hosted on Microsoft Azure, but we have also tried it on a server in our building and that it is also slow.

The insert script is only around 5000 inserts but taking 40+ seconds on the servers. [This happens on all tables, but the one we are testing on has 2 columns, no keys, no constraints, no triggers and no indexes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2eXu.png)

As shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lGTb.png) the insert script took 43 seconds on our server, but on our [local machines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPFAi.png) it only takes 1 second. While the indexes go up to 7761, it is actually just under 5000 INSERT INTO statements.

This is causing considerable slow down for some of our customers and in many cases we are inserting more towards 10000 records, so it is taking 1-2 minutes for them to load a page.

I have tried different versions of SQL server and 3 different servers (2 on Windows 2012, 1 on Windows 2016). Running the insert script on our computer from another computer still has the ~1 insert speeds.

I thought it might have been because our computers have SSD's while the servers have HDD's, but I set it up on a laptop that has a HDD and still had the ~1 second insert times.

I'm not really sure what else to look for as the only difference I can see is that the servers are running Windows 2012/2016, but our computers are all on Windows 10.

What else could be causing this, as I find it unlikely that the windows version is causing this. It seems like there is some setting in the SQL servers that are causing it to be slow on inserts.

EDIT:

The cause of the problem seems to be slow disk speed on the servers. They are capable of much more, but for some reason they max out at around 1MB/s whereas our computers get to around 30MB/s while running the insert query.

I found I could put the inserts into a transaction and it would fix the problem. Still unsure as to why the disk speed is so low.

Comment: Are you sure the databases are identical? Maybe there the allocated resources are limited in the server. Maybe the server is overwhelmed. Maybe is doesn't have enough memory. How many users are using the same server? What about replication? Maybe there is some triggers there.

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes, same database. I have used the same .bak file to restore in all locations I have tested it. All servers we have tried it on have their resources barely being touched when inserting. There are no triggers on this table as I said. The database itself is identical across all places I have tested it, so it has to be something different in the SQL server settings or the server itself.

Comment: Then, the server is overwhelmed. You should check the system load, the memory usage, the number of concurrent users. Also, your DBA should allocate enough resources (CPU, memory, tablespaces, etc.) Otherwise it will continue to be slow.

Comment: @TheImpaler Looking at the resources on the server when the insert happens, the disk usage In Resource Monitor seems to max out at around 1-3MB/s, whereas on my computer it goes straight up to 25-30MB/s. The Highest Active Time jumps to 95% on our servers, but sticks between 40-60% on my computer. Our servers drives are capable of much more than 1MB/s bandwidth. I think this may be because of the Raid setup

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you connect from your local workstation to remote db which is hosted in Azure infratructure. There is one extra aspect which you have to take into consideration **network latency**. Looks like your script sends each insert as a sperate request. You send one request per one row of data and echa time you wait for response from Azure and then you send next record.

Try to use diffrent syntax for this multi insert

```
INSERT INTO wtListingExpand VALUES
  ('a24f0628-dc91...', 7747)
 ,('a24f0628-dc91...', 7747)
 ,('a24f0628-dc91...', 7747)
```

This should send all the data as one big insert request and reduce impact of network latency.

Comment: Thank you, I did think that latency would be a problem, but we were remoting into the server and running the script inside management studio on the server. It should be the same as when we were running it on our local computer. We found that the problem was the disk speed on the server, and putting all the inserts into a transaction fixes the problem. I get the feeling that your suggestion would work the same as putting the inserts into a transaction. the next step is to figure out why the server disk speed wasn't going above 1MB/s